# Habilitar o Proguard em aplicação Android

Tags: android, ofuscação, proguard

Fiz um projeto de exemplo, utilizando `SQLCipher`, e estou tentando ofuscar o código com o `Proguard`, porém, após exportar e assinar a aplicação, e converter o classes.dex com o `dex2jar`, consigo ver praticamente todo o código com o `Java Decompiler`, pois o código não foi ofuscado. Eu gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado na configuração do `Proguard`. Segue a configuração do `proguard-project.txt:`

```
 -injars      bin/classes
 -injars      libs
 -outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
 -libraryjars C:/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platforms/android-        13/android.jar

-optimizations  !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification
-dontpreverify
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes *Annotation* 
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Signature
 # Obfuscation
-repackageclasses ''
-flattenpackagehierarchy ''


-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 }

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
 }

 -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
  }

 -keep public class net.sqlcipher.** {
  *;
  }

-keep public class net.sqlcipher.database.** {
   *;
 }
```

Comment: Talvez estes links possam te ajudar: (1): https://gist.github.com/developernotes/3040592
(2): https://github.com/exmo/equizmo-android/wiki/Ofuscando-aplicativos-Android

Answer (score 1):

Fabio, é possível que seu arquivo proguard-project.txt não esteja sendo aplicado ao projeto. 
Se você estiver usando o Android Studio e Gradle dê uma olhada no build.gradle, procure pela entrada `proguardFiles` e tenha certeza que seu arquivo está listado lá.
Para instruções mais detalhadas dê uma consultada aqui: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: DuCarrara, eu estou usando o Eclipse, e não o Android Studio.

Comment: Fabio dá um conferida no arquivo project.properties na raíz do projeto e veja se a entrada proguard.config está apontando para o seu arquivo proguard.

Comment: Está assim:   proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

Comment: Fabio estou ficando sem ideas :P. Você poderia postar um trecho de exemplo de uma classe antes da obfuscação e depois de aplicar o Java decompiler?

Comment: Pergunto isso porque depende o que você tem em mente como resultado da ofuscação. Este post tem uma explicação interessante sobre o assunot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706084/android-apk-decompilation-seems-to-easy

Comment: DuCarrara, postei o código como resposta.

Comment: Fabio, pelo que parece o proguard está fazendo o trabalho dele sim. O proguard faz a obfuscação do código (muda nome de variáveis, métodos), remove código não utilizado e etc. Como você pode perceber tem algumas variáveis que tiveram seus nomes trocados e as que não foram é porque caem nas -keep (como activities e classes do sqlcipher). Como citado no post que eu coloquei acima se você quer tornar o seu código mais "seguro" por assim dizer só a obfuscação do proguard não será suficiente.

Comment: Esse é um trabalho bem difícil diga-se de passagem, tem um material interessante aqui: http://pt.slideshare.net/godfreynolan/protecting-source-code ou https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard ou http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html . Mas é necessário pesquisar e ver o que realmente se aplica à seu app.

Answer (score 0):

Código original :

```
package com.example.sqlcipher_exemplo;

import java.io.File;

import net.sqlcipher.Cursor;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabaseHook;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    EventDataSQLHelper eventsData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if ("google_sdk".equals( Build.PRODUCT ) || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")) 
        {

               Log.i("EMULADOR", "rodando no emulador");

        } 
        else 
        {
               Log.i("DISPOSITIVO", "rodando no dispositivo");
        }

        SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);
        String password = "123";
        eventsData = new EventDataSQLHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase(password);   
        for(int i=1; i<100; i++)
        {
            addEvent("Hello Android Event "+i, db); 
        }
        db.close();
        db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase(password);
        Cursor cursor = getEvents(db);
        showEvents(cursor);
        db.close();
    }

    private void addEvent (String title, SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EventDataSQLHelper.TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(EventDataSQLHelper.TITLE, title);
        db.insert(EventDataSQLHelper.TABLE, null, values);
    }

    private Cursor getEvents(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        Cursor cursor = db.query(EventDataSQLHelper.TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        return cursor;
    }

    private void showEvents(Cursor cursor)
    {
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder("Saved Events:\n\n");
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
            long time = cursor.getLong(1);
            String title = cursor.getString(2);
            ret.append(id+": "+time+":"+title+"\n");
        }
        Log.i("sqldemo", ret.toString());
    }

    /*
    private void decryptDatabase() 
    {
          File unencryptedFile = getDatabasePath("events.db");
          unencryptedFile.delete();
          File databaseFile = getDatabasePath("events.db");
          SQLiteDatabaseHook hook = new SQLiteDatabaseHook() {
           public void preKey(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            sqLiteDatabase
              .rawExecSQL("PRAGMA cipher_default_use_hmac = off;");
           }

           public void postKey(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) 
           {

           }
          };
          SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(
            databaseFile, "123", null, hook); // Exception 
          if (database.isOpen()) 
          {
           database.rawExecSQL(String.format(
             "ATTACH DATABASE '%s' as plaintext KEY '';",
             unencryptedFile.getAbsolutePath()));
           database.rawExecSQL("SELECT sqlcipher_export('plaintext');");
           database.rawExecSQL("DETACH DATABASE plaintext;");
           android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
             .openOrCreateDatabase(unencryptedFile, null);
           sqlDB.close();
           database.close();
          }

          databaseFile.delete();
    }*/
}
```

Código depois do Proguard:

```
package com.example.sqlcipher_exemplo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import net.sqlcipher.Cursor;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;

public class MainActivity
  extends Activity
{
  a a;

  private Cursor a(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase)
  {
    paramSQLiteDatabase = paramSQLiteDatabase.query("events", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(paramSQLiteDatabase);
    return paramSQLiteDatabase;
  }

  private void a(String paramString, SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase)
  {
    ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();
    localContentValues.put("time", Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    localContentValues.put("title", paramString);
    paramSQLiteDatabase.insert("events", null, localContentValues);
  }

  private void a(Cursor paramCursor)
  {
    StringBuilder localStringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Saved Events:\n\n");
    for (;;)
    {
      if (!paramCursor.moveToNext())
      {
        Log.i("sqldemo", localStringBuilder.toString());
        return;
      }
      long l1 = paramCursor.getLong(0);
      long l2 = paramCursor.getLong(1);
      String str = paramCursor.getString(2);
      localStringBuilder.append(l1 + ": " + l2 + ":" + str + "\n");
    }
  }

  protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(2130903040);
    int i;
    if (("google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT)) || (Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")))
    {
      Log.i("EMULADOR", "rodando no emulador");
      SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);
      this.a = new a(this);
      paramBundle = this.a.getWritableDatabase("123");
      i = 1;
    }
    for (;;)
    {
      if (i >= 100)
      {
        paramBundle.close();
        paramBundle = this.a.getReadableDatabase("123");
        a(a(paramBundle));
        paramBundle.close();
        return;
        Log.i("DISPOSITIVO", "rodando no dispositivo");
        break;
      }
      a("Hello Android Event " + i, paramBundle);
      i += 1;
    }
  }
}
```